# webpack compiled successfully but no result is shown

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have imported all the routers, but when I go to the localhost server website, all I see is a blank page. I have set up the home pages and the others.

```
import React from "react";
import './App.css';

import Home from "./pages/Home";
import Rooms from "./pages/Rooms";
import SingleRoom from "./pages/SingleRoom";
import Error from "./pages/Error";

import {Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom";

import Navbar from "./components/Navbar"

function App() {
  return (
    <>
    <Navbar />
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={<Home/>} />
      <Route exact path="/rooms/" component={<Rooms/>} />
      <Route exact path="/rooms/:slug" component={<SingleRoom/>} />
      <Route component={<Error/>} />
    </Switch>
    

    
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The following is index.js file, where I import the browser router.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <App />
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

I checked the routers import and couldn't see where is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the updated index.js file for your problem.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
   <Router>
    <App />
  </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: It still shows nothing:(